# Modal no muestra registros del id

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

Estoy haciendo un sistema de agenda de reuniones con la librería de php Calendar. Resulta que tengo 2 modals: uno para agregar reunión y el otro para editar reunión. Cada usuario tiene un login para crear una reunión, y cuando el usuario entra solo ve su reunión creada, sin embargo hay un administrador que ver todas las reuniones: eso estoy manejando por sessions. Cuando el usuario entra a su session puede ver, editar y eliminar una reunión, pero el problema que estoy teniendo es que el admin que ve todas las reuniones no puede editar, o sea que el modal que se abre para editar no me muestra los registros de dicho usuario.

No entiendo por qué no está pasando el id bien, hice un `var_dump()` y dice null, no sé si es porque están los dos formularios en la misma página, pero lo extraño es que el usuario cuando entra en su session él sí puede editar, pero el admin no.

¿Dónde estoy equivocándome?

> Hace 15 días que vengo trabajando en eso sin solución, de última si no hay solución les digo que no se puede editar y listo.

Les comparto los códigos que estoy trabajando.

Login.php

```
session_start();
$user = isset($_POST['user']) ? $_POST['user'] : NULL;
$pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : NULL;
if ($user === "s" && $pass === "s") {
  $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
    $_SESSION["area"] = “admin”;
    header("Location: home-admin.php");
}
elseif($user === "a" && $pass === "a") {
  $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
  $_SESSION["area"] = “Deposito”;
  header("Location: home.php");
}
```

home.php

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user"]) || (!empty($_SESSION["usuario"]) && $_SESSION["user"] !== 'admin' && $_SESSION["usuario"] !== 'usuario')) {
    $_SESSION["area"];
    header("Location: entrar.html");
  exit();
}

$area =  $_SESSION["area"];
// Sentencia sql para traer las agenda desde la base de datos segun su area
if($area == ‘admin){
    header('Location:home-admin.php'); 
}else{
    
}
```

MODALES
home.php

```
<!—MODAL DE EDITAR QUE SI ME TRAE LOS DATOS>
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_evento" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
        <?php

        //CODIGO DE ACTUALIZACION

        $id = (!empty ($_GET['id']) ) ? $_GET['id'] : NULL; 

        $title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : NULL;
        $class = isset($_POST['class']) ? $_POST['class'] : NULL;

        $basedatos = "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE title = '$area'"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $basedatos);
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        ?>  
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Editar Reunion: <?php echo 'ID: '.$fila['id']; ?></h4>
        </div>  
        <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="procesar_editar_evento.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>" name="id">
        <label for="from2">Inicio actual:</label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='from2'>
        <input type='text' id="from2" name="from2" class="form-control" required placeholder="<?php echo date('d/m/Y h:i A', strtotime($fila['inicio_normal'])); ?>"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <label for="to2">Final actual:</label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='to2'>
        <input type='text' name="to2" id="to2" class="form-control" required placeholder="<?php echo date('d/m/Y h:i A', strtotime($fila['final_normal'])); ?>"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="contador">
        <br>
        <label for="class">SALA</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="class" id="tipo" required>
        <option value="<?php echo  $fila['class']; ?>"><?php echo  $fila['class']; ?></option>
        <option value="SALA 1913">SALA 1913</option>
        <option value="SALA T">SALA T</option>
        <option value="VESTUARIO">VESTUARIO</option>
        <option value="SALA TECNICA">SALA TECNICA</option>
        <option value="SALA DE PRENSA">SALA DE PRENSA</option>
        </select>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="title">AREA</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["area"];?>" disabled />
        <br>
        <label for="body">Descripcion</label>
        <textarea id="body" name="event" class="form-control" rows="3" required><?php echo  $fila['body']; ?></textarea>
                        
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Guardar</button>
        </form>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
<!--FIN FORMULARIO EDITAR REUNION-->
```

```
home-admin.php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM agenda"; //muestra todas las reuniones

<!—MODAL QUE NO DEBERIA TRAER LOS DATOS DE LA REUNION SEGUN EL ID PARA PODER EDITAR-->
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_evento" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
        <?php

        //CODIGO DE ACTUALIZACION

        //$id = (!empty ($_GET['id']) ) ? $_GET['id'] : NULL; 

        $title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : NULL;
        $class = isset($_POST['class']) ? $_POST['class'] : NULL;

        $basedatos = "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE id = '$id'"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $basedatos);
        $fila2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        ?>  
    
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Editar Reunion: <?php echo 'ID: '.$fila2['id']; ?></h4>
        </div>  
        <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="procesar_editar_evento.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fila2['id']; ?>" name="id">
            
        <label for="from2">Inicio actual:</label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='from2'>
            
        <input type='text' id="from2" name="from" class="form-control" required placeholder="<?php echo date('d/m/Y h:i A', strtotime($fila2['inicio_normal'])); ?>"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </div>
        <br>

        <label for="to2">Final actual:</label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='to2'>
        <input type='text' name="to" id="to2" class="form-control" required placeholder="<?php echo date('d/m/Y h:i A', strtotime($fila2['final_normal'])); ?>"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="contador">
        <br>

        <label for="class">SALA</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="class" id="class" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Elija la sala</option>
        <option value="SALA 1">SALA 1</option>
        <option value="SALA 2”>SALA 2</option>

        </select>
        <br>
                        
        <label for="title">AREA</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="title" id="title" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Elija Area</option>
        <option value="Deposito">Deposito</option>
        <option value="Mantenimiento">Mantenimiento</option>

        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="body">Descripcion</label>
        <textarea id="body" name="event" class="form-control" rows="3" required><?php echo  $fila2['body']; ?></textarea>
                        
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Guardar</button>
        </form>
        <!--FIN DE FORMULARIO-->
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
<!--FIN FORMULARIO EDITAR REUNION-->
```

link boton editar

```
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <a href="#?id=<%= event.id %>" alt="EDITAR REUNION" title="EDITAR REUNION" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_evento">
                    <span class="editar">Editar</span>
                </a>
```